# DNS not resolving

Tags: networking, dns

Both on WiFi and mobile data, DNS resolutions fail instantaneously.  I can load sites by IP address in Firefox, and I can connect to other machines using SSH by IP address, but anything that requires a hostname fails.

nslookup claims to using 0.0.0.0 as its name server.  When I specify the server to use, such as 8.8.8.8, nslookup always fails: `nslookup: can't resolve 'startpage.com'`

Sometimes after rebooting DNS works for a few seconds.

This is a rooted Samsung Galaxy SIII running Cyanogenmod 11 nightly build, Android version 4.4.4.  The problem was the same on SlimKat.

Comment: When did the problem start? Was it as soon as you installed a custom ROM? Have you installed an ad-blocker, firewall, or similar?

Comment: I can't think of any changes that correlate.

Comment: I flashed an update to CyanogenMod and the problem is gone for now.

Comment: If the problem is solved, you should answer your own question so it no longer shows up as unanswered. CM nightly builds commonly have problems like this: that's why they're not recommended for everyday use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared when a newer CyanogenMod build was flashed.

(The problem was present on a stable SlimKat ROM as well.)